# Unable to cast COM object of Office Interop Word

Tags: .net, com, ms-office, office-interop

My application has a feature to export to Microsoft Word, but it hasn't worked since I've upgraded from Microsoft Office 2010 to Microsoft Office 2013.

Here is the code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appVersion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
appVersion.Visible = false;
```

and this is the error message:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Someone told me to edit the registry, but the IID "{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" does not exist in my registry.

Comment: That's what the exception message means, COM could not find the registry key either.  Reinstall after trying to find out why the registry is corrupted.  And *do* try to run code on an STA thread, this marshaling isn't very cheap.

Answer (score 5):

Running a repair installation of Office usually resolves that issue.

Comment: In the case that this doesn't work, is there any further debug that can be performed?

Answer (score 2):

I switched from using Word Interop to using Late Binding.  Quick fix that didn't affect refactoring a lot of code...

Before:

```
OfficeWord.Application msword = new OfficeWord.Application();
```

After:

```
Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
dynamic msword = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);
```

Solved my issues on a bunch of corporate computers that started seeing this problem after an Office upgrade by Client Support.

Comment: now I know a real use for dynamic, thanks ))

Comment: It worked for me as many other solutions did not work who suggest to repair office or install again etc

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and reinstalling Office 2013 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but since I had the same issue, I found a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto).

It might help others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, however I ran into the same thing, same exact error message when trying to create a new word application.  The problem was simple, once I closed VS in frustration and went to do other work. When I opened word, it had retrieved documents that had not been saved when Word closed down and wanted to know what I wanted to do with them.  I told it to delete them, closed word and my code worked fine.  Still working on a way around this but I thought I would drop this in here to save someone else from reinstalling office when it was something simple.